# Eyeblaster Ad Tags API

Tags: media, openx

Any one know where i can find the mediamind Eyeblaster Ad Tags API

like below example url (generate from eyeblaster)

http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli={i will not provide my id}&PluID=0&w=300&h=250&ucm=true&ifl=$$http://www.mydomain.com/eyeblaster/addineyeV2.html$$&ncu=$$http://www.xxxxx.com$$&ord=

i want to know the definition of  ifl and ncu

since i will to integrate with some ads system like openx (although already integrate in this system by using a tag to wrap the ad tag script)

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your question :

**ifl** is locate to a html which only contain a html code

**ncu** is a parameter defined by MediaMind which is normally used by the Ad server to track clicks. It can be used for custom logging URL's that is we can pass the required Custom URL's.

Comment: Actually ifl is the place which to locate the iframe breaker that provided by ad server, ncu is custom logging url, sorry i forgot to close the question